# How to add minutes to a Time object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

In Ruby, how do I do `Time.now + 10.hours`?

Is there an equivalent for `secs` and `mins`?  For example:

```
Time.now + 15.mins
```

Comment: It doesn't work the other way round: 
`10 + Time.now`:
`TypeError: Time can't be coerced into Fixnum`
but `Time.now + 10` works.. for all who have the same problem ;)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Ruby (the programming language) doesn't have `10.hours`, that's `ActiveSupport` as part of Ruby on Rails (the web framework). And yes, it does have both [`minutes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-minutes) and [`seconds`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-seconds) methods.

However, [`Time#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000357) (the + method on Time instances) returns a new Time instance that is that many seconds in the future. So without any Ruby on Rails sugar, you can simply do:

```
irb> t = Time.now
#=> 2011-08-03 22:35:01 -0600

irb> t2 = t + 10               # 10 Seconds
#=> 2011-08-03 22:35:11 -0600

irb> t3 = t + 10*60            # 10 minutes
#=> 2011-08-03 22:45:01 -0600

irb> t4 = t + 10*60*60         # 10 hours
#=> 2011-08-04 08:35:01 -0600
```

Comment: @NailsonLandim, you might well find [Timerizer](https://github.com/kylewlacy/timerizer) useful. "Rails time syntax without the Rails."

Comment: The appropriate part of the Core Extensions documentation is https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date and the following two sections.

Answer (score 82):

If you are using ActiveSupport, what you are looking for is the full `.minutes` and `.seconds`.

```
Time.now + 10.minutes
Time.now + 10.seconds
```

Comment: Warning: This is not commutative! You must put `Time.now + 10.seconds` rather than `10.seconds + Time.now`

Answer (score 24):

Also in ActiveSupport you can do:

```
10.minutes.from_now

10.minutes.ago
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about extensions added by Rails. I think you need `15.minutes`.

See the [Active Support Core Extensions for Date, DateTime and Time](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Time Object

`time = Time.now`

Adding minutes to a time object:

`time + 5.minutes`

Answer (score 0):

There is an advance function in Active Support [refer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#other-extensions-advance).

You can do the following using advance:

```rb
d = DateTime.new(2010, 2, 28, 23, 59, 59) 
=> Sun, 28 Feb 2010 23:59:59 +0000
d.advance(hours: 1) 
=> Mon, 01 Mar 2010 00:59:59 +0000
```